# jQuery Mobile Theme Roller Generates Broken Theme?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a swatch which I created using the jQuery Mobile themeroller (http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/?ver=1.1.1&style_id=20120909-36). It looks like this in the themeroller:

[image]

... but downloading and installing it as directed looks like this:

[image]

I have installed the theme as directed in the `<head>` section of my page, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/Bon%20Cuisson/project-files/bin-debug/system/stylesheets/bc-swatch-mobile.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone tell me as to why the CSS appears broken, even though it was only a direct copy and paste?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The first stylesheet URL looks quite weird, did you double check that one?

Comment: @StevenRoose Yes, it is properly linked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm... I originally generated this theme with only one swatch. By duplicating this swatch twice (giving me a total of three, identical, swatches) and retrying the installation, it worked. I just followed jQM's recommendation for a minimum of 3 swatches, and then it worked no problem.

Why? No clue, but I hope that can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery Mobile by default assigns different swatch letters to different controls. Swatch a for header and footers, b on listviws, nested list page headers and c on content blocks.I suspect this could be the reason why you need more than 1? [Jquery Mobile Themes and Defaults](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/api/themes.html)